# VB>NET database connectivity with a table having checkboxes

Tags: vb.net

Can anyone help me how to insert the code to move to the next record of the database in a table that has one CHECKBOX? i tried using the regular method of 
checkbox1=.Item("BookingStatus").ToString
but it gives a runtime error

Answer (score 0):

As klabranche says, it's difficult to be sure without more information but I think you're probably looking for either of:

```
checkbox1.checked = CBool(.Item("BookingStatus"))  

checkbox1.checked = .Item("BookingStatus").ToString().Equals("X")
```

Where X is some kind of status.

Just remember that if BookingStatus might be NULL you might have to check for that first as well.